# What is $(-1)^\infty$, or $(-1)^x$ as the limit of $x$ approaches infinity?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits, infinity

I typed it into Symbolab calculator and it said that the solution diverges, though in real numbers the solution would never go past 1. Why is this?

Comment: Because it oscillates and never "settles down."

Comment: "Diverge" means "does not converge" (not "is unbounded"). And it does not converge, indeed. Also, I'm curious about what you mean -- is $x$ always an integer for you in this setting? If not, how do you interpret $(-1)^{1/2}$, for instance?)

Comment: I wond interpret root(-1) equal to i, the imaginary number, which certainly does converge. I originally thought that diverge meant something like growing infinitely.

Comment: We would need some more context for the set-up, since it really matters what values $x$ takes.  You can certainly ask the question if $x$ is natural, in which case there is a legal definition of "convergence" and this sequence does not meet it.

Answer (score 0):

We do not define $(-1)^x$ for all real numbers because it ends up with non-real answers.

Thus you may say the limit is undefined.

Limit Does not exist is another answer, but I prefer undefined in this case.